# Restarting Windows Store Apps programmatically

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs

I know that one can use `MSApp.terminateApp` to kill the application. What about restarting an app? Is there any command for restarting?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @JPAlioto Sometimes when my app gets into a unrecoverable state, I would like to offer user to restart the application instead of getting stuck there.

Comment: or maybe to activate the newly selected language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting does not fit within the Windows 8 Application concept (formerly metro).  If you get into an unrecoverable state then the appropriate thing to do is let it crash and let windows handle it from there.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx#app_crash):

> App crash
>
> Apps are required to follow the system crash experience, which is to
>   simply return to the Start screen. The system crash experience is
>   designed to get users back to what they were doing as quickly as
>   possible, so you shouldn't provide a warning dialog or other
>   notification because that'll cause a delay for the user. The
>   disappearance of the app should make it clear to the user that
>   something went wrong.
>
> If your app crashes, stops responding, or generates an exception,
>   Windows asks the user for consent to send a problem report to
>   Microsoft. Microsoft provides a subset of the error data in the
>   problem report to you so that you can use it to improve your app.
>   You'll be able to see this data in your app's Quality page in your
>   Dashboard in the Windows Dev Center for Metro style apps. (Note that
>   you can't submit apps or view your app's data until the Windows Store
>   opens for general submissions.)
>
> When the user activates an app after it crashes, its activation event
>   handler receives an ApplicationExecutionState value of NotRunning, and
>   should simply display its initial UI and data.

Comment: In my case, I'm trying to restart the app when a user logs out. Seems the simplest way to clear the data and let the user log in again, like she always has to if no user data is available.

Comment: @pipedreambomb If I were to do something of that sort, I would probably put all of my login data etc into an object and then simply replace that object on logout.

Comment: Absolutely, it already was stored in roamingSettings, so I've now put in a call to clear that. It's a shame I can't just get the app to relaunch from scratch however, after I've done that, so the whole UI gets refreshed instead of manually needing to tear it all down and get it to look like it did when launched.